# SpriteKit - No Contact when Dynamic

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicscontact

My problem is when me hero make contact with an obstacle he rotates and gets affected by that contact, if i set dynamic = false, contact stops getting detected. here is what my hero looks like:

```
    hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: hero.size)
    hero.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = heroGroup
    hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = obstacleGroup
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when the hero makes contact with an obstacle?

Comment: i want to detect that contact but my hero doesn't get affected by it, meaning he doesn't get blocked, or change direction..etc

Comment: You can achieve that by setting `hero.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0` or by unsetting the appropriate `obstacleGroup` bits by `hero.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask &= ~(obstacleGroup)`.